# Script cant find file in linux subsystem windows

Tags: scripts, tcsh

So i have a folder "gib" in my ubuntu root directory. But this line of a script:

```
#! /bin/tcsh -f
setenv  GIBBS /gib
set gibbs = $GIBBS/GibbsCluster-2.0e_SA.pl
```

This always gives error that file GibbsCluster-2.0e_SA.pl not found. Anyone can tell me how to properly set the env path so that the file will be found? The windows location of the file is: I:\Linux\ubuntu\rootfs\gib

But in ubuntu, the directory is is located in /gib
How do i put the address correctly in the script so that the file will be found?

Comment: Why have you tagged this as bash? This looks like csh, maybe

Comment: @muru fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In `csh` and `tcsh`. You can simply do:

```
set GIBBS="/gib"
```

then:

```
set gibbs="$GIBBS/GibbsCluster-2.0e_SA.pl"
```

You can then test the variable with `echo "$gibbs"`